# Keyboards installed and keyboards available not matching on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I am facing a problem with multiple keyboards. double (") quotes shows up as (@). On researching the problem, I found out it is because I have the UK keyboard selected. However, this leads me to another problem. I do not have a UK keyboard installed ! (see screenshot below)

[image: Here is a screenshot from my laptop]

Am I missing some setting somewhere ?

Comment: Delete the UK keyboard and add the correct one matching what you have.

Comment: @DavidPostill I do not have a UK keyboard installed.